# Localize month names in DatePicker

Tags: antd

Is it possible to translate month names in the antd DatePicker?
Moment is set to my current locale da_DK, but that doesn't change the names, and I've looked at the [localization example](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/date-picker/locale/example.json), but no month names are included.

Is it possible?

This is the relevant code:

moment.js:

```
import moment from 'moment';
moment.locale('da-DK');
console.log(moment().format('LLLL')); // This works. Moment displays localized date.
```

antd:

```
import { LocaleProvider } from 'antd';
import defaults from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US';

const da = _.merge(defaults, {
  Table: {
    emptyText: 'Ingen data tilgængelig.',
  }
  // month translations here?
});

<LocaleProvider locale={da}>
  <App.... />
</LocaleProvider>
```

Comment: antd uses momentjs for month names, did you set the locale and use `<LocalProvider>`? you should post your code

Comment: I've added the relevant code.

Comment: `antd` doesn't include Danish presently - https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/tree/master/components/date-picker/locale

Comment: I'm aware. But I can translate it manually, like the rest of the components. But I'm not seeing the properties to be translated for month names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Danish locale to the `antd` global object with the following:

```
const { LocaleProvider, DatePicker, locales, version } = antd;
moment.locale('da');

antd.locales.da = {"locale":"da","Pagination":{"items_per_page":"/ page","jump_to":"Goto","page":"","prev_page":"Previous Page","next_page":"Next Page","prev_5":"Previous 5 Pages","next_5":"Next 5 Pages","prev_3":"Previous 3 Pages","next_3":"Next 3 Pages"},"DatePicker":{"lang":{"placeholder":"Select date","rangePlaceholder":["Start date","End date"],"today":"Today (but in Danish)","now":"Now","backToToday":"Back to today","ok":"Ok","clear":"Clear","month":"Month","year":"Year","timeSelect":"Select time","dateSelect":"Select date","monthSelect":"Choose a month","yearSelect":"Choose a year","decadeSelect":"Choose a decade","yearFormat":"YYYY","dateFormat":"D/M/YYYY","dayFormat":"D","dateTimeFormat":"D/M/YYYY HH:mm:ss","monthBeforeYear":true,"previousMonth":"Previous month (PageUp)","nextMonth":"Next month (PageDown)","previousYear":"Last year (Control + left)","nextYear":"Next year (Control + right)","previousDecade":"Last decade","nextDecade":"Next decade","previousCentury":"Last century","nextCentury":"Next century"},"timePickerLocale":{"placeholder":"Select time"}},"TimePicker":{"placeholder":"Select time"},"Calendar":{"lang":{"placeholder":"Select date","rangePlaceholder":["Start date","End date"],"today":"Today","now":"Now","backToToday":"Back to today","ok":"Ok","clear":"Clear","month":"Month","year":"Year","timeSelect":"Select time","dateSelect":"Select date","monthSelect":"Choose a month","yearSelect":"Choose a year","decadeSelect":"Choose a decade","yearFormat":"YYYY","dateFormat":"D/M/YYYY","dayFormat":"D","dateTimeFormat":"D/M/YYYY HH:mm:ss","monthBeforeYear":true,"previousMonth":"Previous month (PageUp)","nextMonth":"Next month (PageDown)","previousYear":"Last year (Control + left)","nextYear":"Next year (Control + right)","previousDecade":"Last decade","nextDecade":"Next decade","previousCentury":"Last century","nextCentury":"Next century"},"timePickerLocale":{"placeholder":"Select time"}},"Table":{"filterTitle":"Filter menu","filterConfirm":"OK","filterReset":"Reset","emptyText":"No data","selectAll":"Select current page","selectInvert":"Invert current page"},"Modal":{"okText":"OK","cancelText":"Cancel","justOkText":"OK"},"Popconfirm":{"okText":"OK","cancelText":"Cancel"},"Transfer":{"notFoundContent":"Not Found","searchPlaceholder":"Search here","itemUnit":"item","itemsUnit":"items"},"Select":{"notFoundContent":"Not Found"},"Upload":{"uploading":"Uploading...","removeFile":"Remove file","uploadError":"Upload error","previewFile":"Preview file"}};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <p className="version">antd version: {version}</p>
    <LocaleProvider locale={locales.da}>
      <DatePicker defaultValue={moment()} />   
    </LocaleProvider>
  </div>
, mountNode);
```

Demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRaGve?editors=0010

(Sadly, despite watching every season of the Borgen my Danish is next to non-existent. I leave the above translations with you...)

Comment: From my point of view, you're not doing anything different than I. Looking at moments documentation, I'm thinking that this could be the issue: "As of 2.8.0, changing the global locale doesn't affect existing instances"

Comment: It doesn't look like you are matching up the locale in `_.merge(defaults, {... `.  I have `antd.locales.da = {"locale":"da",...`.  Have you tried the demo link?  It shows the months in Danish

Comment: Oooh, you are correct. Adding `locale: "da"` to my const `da` made the difference. So antd must be using that constant in the DatePicker when instantiating the moment object. Thanks alot.

Comment: `antd` uses the month names from `Moment` so it needs that to connect to Moment's locale

Comment: Correct. My mistake was that I thought it was sufficient to set `moment.locale('da');`, but it wasn't.